# Who are Jambhini, Tulaja Devi and Mohini?

Tags: identification-request, shaktism

In [this chapter](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/devi-bhagavata-purana/d/doc57285.html) of Devi Bhagavatha says the Dasha Mahavidyas, Kamakshi, Guhyakali, Jambhini, Mohini and Tulaja Devi are emerged from Devi Shakambhari.

But, i don't know about Jambhini, Tulaja Devi and Mohini. So my questions are:-

- Who are them? Is any mention about them is mentioned in any Puranas or other scriptures?
- Is that Mohini (who was emerged from Devi) and Vishnu's Mohini Avatar are same ?

I want clear my doubt. Please clear my doubt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the two Mohinis are different. There is no other mention in the rest of the Devi Bhagavata Purana, and one other mention of Jambhini in the [Garuda Purana,](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-garuda-purana-dutt/d/doc122686.html) when Hari explains what to do in cases of illness:

> O Rudra, put into the hands of a fever-patient eight hundred flowers, each consecrated with the mystic formula, "***Om Jambhini, Stambhini*** (destroying and paralysing goddess), ***Mohaya*** (make spellbound) **Sarva Vyadhin** (all diseases) ***Mé*** ***Vajréna Thah Thah Sarva Vyadhin Vajrena"***...All forms of fever and specially quotidian ague may be destroyed by practising this fever-charm.

So this tells us that Jambhini was a destructive force. That's all I could find on Jambhini.

Tulaja Devi *could* have been the source of Tulaja Bhavani, a form of Parvati who seems to be worshipped in various places around India. Perhaps she had some sort of association with the earth.

There aren't any other mentions of Mohini Devi in any of the Puranas that I could find.

---

The same story that you mention is analyzed in the book [*Tantric Visions of the Divine Feminine: The Ten Mahavidyas*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Tantric_Visions_of_the_Divine_Feminine/iob2JIzY9fIC?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=Jambhini,)

> ﻿A fierce battle then began between the goddess and the demon and his armies. The goddess created several groups of goddess allies to help her in this fight, and among them were the Mahavidyās. The text says that these goddesses are her principal saktis and have emerged directly from her body. It names them in the following order: Kālikā, Tāriņī, Tripura, Bhairavī, Kamalā, Bagalā, Mātangī, Tripura-sundarī, Kamākṣā, **Tulajā-devī, Jambhini, Mohini**, and Chinnamastā. The Devi-bhāgavata-purāṇa does not mention the Mahavidyas again.

[This](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Manoram%C4%81%E1%B9%ADik%C4%81/edIJ3J2sn4EC?hl=en&gbpv=0&bsq=Jambhini) book claims that they are Avarana Shakti's, but I can't be so sure whether that's true. But all the above information is what I could find.